# How to add a computable value if statement is True in an excel sheet formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])

*This is my formula:*

```
=IF(AND($B$3=B5, $C$3=C5),BQ5+3,IF(AND($B$3> $C$3, B5>C5),BQ5+1,IF(AND($B$3< $C$3, B5<C5),BQ5+1,IF(AND($B$3= $C$3, B5=C5),BQ5+1,0))))
```

*This is not being calculated:*

```
 BQ5+3
```

**What is the correct way to write down a formula likes this?** I want to add 3 to the `BQ5` cell.

Comment: What are the values in B3, B5, C3, C5 ?

Comment: Formula itself is fine. There must be something wrong with your first comparison (probably cell values).

Comment: If you want the value in `BQ5` to change, that is not possible using formula... You will need VBA to achieve that. However, in a new cell using formula you can produce the value that is `BQ5` + 3

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor yes i was thinking the same too. But i just wanted to make sure there was no work around using a formula.

Answer (score 0):

`BQ5+3` should be calculated. You are probably not seeing it. Try like this and then slowly replace in your formula:

```
=IF(AND(1=1,2=2),BQ5+3,"SOMETHING")
```

`AND(1=1,2=2)` would be always evaluated to `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not being calculated it is always = `0` instead of `3` when i changed values to give me `False` it worked fine and it was written `"SOMETHING"` in the cell.